# Assign multiple $http return data to an array in the called order

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, http

```
$scope.iter = 0;                         
$scope.myArray.forEach(function () {   
  $http.get($scope.myArray[$scope.iter].URL)
   .success(function (data) {
    $scope.myArray2.push(data);
    //$scope.myArray2[$scope.iter]=data
    });
$scope.iter++;
})
```

The above code works but I want the results in myArray2 in the same order as it was called. I know that I cannot expect $scope.myArray2[$scope.iter]=data to work but that is what I need.

I looked at the angular documentation on promises but could not make out how to use it for the above.

Answer (score 2):

You can put all promises from the get requests in an array and use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) to create a promise that resolves when all underlying promises resolve. You can then iterate the responses in the order they were added to the requests array, and push each response's data into the array in order...

```
function controller ($scope, $q) {

    // ...

    var requests = [];      
    var $scope.myArray2 = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.myArray, function (value) {   
        requests.push($http.get(value.URL));
    });

    $q.all(requests).then(function(results) {
        angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
            $scope.myArray2.push(result.data);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I have to wait for all the underlying promises to resolve? How can I assign each to its correct place in myArray2 as it is being resolved?

Comment: You don't have to wait. The results array will contain... well... the 'result' ( ajax response payload) in the order the promise was added to the `requests` array. Here is the working fiddle, Anthony beat me to it ;). http://fiddle.jshell.net/3C8R3/3/

Comment: And also the fiddle with a random delay in the response, to prove that promises do retain their order --> http://fiddle.jshell.net/3C8R3/4/

Comment: $q.all() won't resolve till all underlying promises resolve, so yes, with this method you have to wait for all of them to resolve before you can iterate the results. To do it as they get resolved, you have to think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

Dont understand what you are trying to achieve, but here is an example of simple deferred promises in a controller:

```
var firstDefer= $q.defer();

firstDefer.promise.then(function(thing){
    // here you make the first request,
    // only when the first request is completed
    //the variable that you return will be filled and
    //returned. The thing that you return in the first .then
   // is the parameter that you receive in the second .then
    return thingPlusRequestData;
}).then(function(thingPlusRequestData){
    //second request

    return thingPlusPlusRequestData;
}).then(function(thingPlusPlusRequestData){
    //and so on...
});

firstDefer.resolve(thing);
    //when you call .resolve it tries to "accomplish" the first promise
  //you can pass something if you want as a parameter and it will be
 // the first .then parameter.
```

Hope this helps u :D

Answer (score 0):

You will normally NOT get the results in the order you called the `$http.get(...)` function. Mind that the `success(...)` function is called asynchronously, whenever the http response comes in, and the order of those responses is totaly unpredictable.

However you can work around this by waiting for all the responses to finish, and then sort them according to your criteria.

Here is the working fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/3C8R3/3/